# How peek and map works in streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to understand how different peek and map in java 8 streams.I have tried the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> arr = new  ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("A");
        arr.add("B");

        List<String> a = arr.stream().peek(t->t.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

The above code is not changing the alphabets to lower case.But when i try the following

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> arr = new  ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("A");
        arr.add("B");

        List<String> a = arr.stream().map(t->t.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

The alphabets are converted to smaller case.My doubt here is if i use both map and peek like below

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> arr = new  ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("A");
        arr.add("B");

        List<String> a = arr.stream().map(t->t.toLowerCase()).peek(t->toUpper()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static  Function<String, String> toUpper(){
        return t->{
            return t.toUpperCase();
        };
    }
```

The map method converts A,B to lower and Peek does nothing.So if there is any calculation involved while streaming cant i make use of peek?Can someone explain

MOdified code

```
static  List<Employee> e = new  ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> arr = new  ArrayList<String>();
    arr.add("Pavan");
    arr.add("Kumar");


    System.out.println("Size of emp"+e.size());
    List<String> a = arr.stream().map(t->t.toLowerCase()).peek(t->populateEmp()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("Size of emp"+e.size());
    System.out.println(a);
}

public static  Function<String, Employee> populateEmp(){
    Employee ee = new  Employee();
    return t->{
        System.out.println(t);
        ee.setName(t);
        e.add(ee);
        return ee;
    };
}
```

This is still not adding the Emp to list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Peek expects a **[Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)**, so if you are using toLowerCase() you are creating a new String, which is put into void. You may modify this object inside of a consumer, but String is immutable, so peek has no effect.

When you use **map**, then you expect to pass a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) or [UnaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html), that receives single object and returns single object. So new String that is lower-cased is returned.

In both cases, objects are not cloned. So you could modify an object that is mutable inside of a peek function, but that is just the wrong way to do it:) Try passing a Date, then you can set hours inside a peek function because it's mutable.

In short:

- use map to transform model to another model
- use peek, to do something that consumes this object, but **does not modify it** (send a notification, print model, etc)

UPDATE:

```
public static Function<String, Employee> populateEmp(){
        Employee ee = new  Employee();
        System.out.print("I am executed");
        return t->{
            System.out.print("I am not");
            return null;
        };
    }
```

Try with this code. In your update, you are passing a consumer, that ignores passed argument, and you execute `populateEmp()` method, which returns a function, that adds to a map transformed object. But you **NEVER** execute this function, tus-> list is empty:)

In non-lambda word it looks like this:

```
for(String value: arr){
     populateEmp(); // execute method but you do nothing with this Function.
}
```

So replace your peek with this:

```
.peek(t->populateEmp().apply(t))
```

Comment: What if i add this Strings to a list in the peek ..Does this add the strings to List?

Comment: When you use a stream on a list, peek, and map apply to each list elements. So if you have a stream of lists, then you can add to each list something inside a peek. Same as pass a list to method, and modify it there. But that is bad practise as I said.